# multiple image changes for many buttons (javascript equivalent of GET)

Tags: javascript, php, loops, variables, get

I code in php better and am kind of sick of page refreshes. I would like an image to change with the click of a button. But this button is generated by an sql query that generates a random sample so i want an image associated with the item clicked. so for the id from select statement, i want the matching image
(select id,image from table).
Please help i can't manually load 50 functions as am using a loop for the button. I need a form of GET statement to say button X has ben clicked so load the matching picture from the database (select statement). Thanks
Anne

Comment: Here's my code <?php for ($ex = 0; $ex< count($ext); $ex++) { ?>
<button id=<? echo $ext[$ex]['productid'] ?> onclick="changeImage();"><?php echo $ext[$ex]['productname'] ?>Click  image!</button>
<?php } ?>         <script>
function changeImage()
{
var img = document.getElementById("image");
//img.src="images/shiraz.jpg";
img.src="<?php echo $ext2[0]['imagepath'] ?>";

return false;
}
</script>

Comment: Do you think this is readable?

Comment: "I code in php better". I beg to differ. There are more things wrong with that php than I have fingers to count on. Also please read: [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Badacadabra I don't know how to post code here

Comment: @gforce301  All my php is doing exactly what i want it to do. It's the javascipt i am struggling with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't understand clearly...

So from your code you want to get clicke button id and src...

So try this...

```
for ($ex = 0; $ex< count($ext); $ex++) 
{ 

echo "<button onClick =ChangeImage(' ". $ext[$ex]. ['productid']."','".$ext2[0]['imagepath']."')> </button>";

}
```

Single common javascript to get clicked button image id and src

```
function ChangeImage(x, y) 
{
// you get id and src of clicked button
alert(x+' & '+y); 

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Subi. My data set has about 200 records so i cant individually set variables. I landed on  a fix and here's the answer, I added this to my button to collect the imagepath for that button that has been clicked.(not sure how to post code here separately) data-imagepath='<?php echo $ext[$ex]['imagepath']; ?>'

Comment: This is the function <script>
function changeImage()
{
window.butid = (event.currentTarget.id);
window.plant = document.getElementById(butid);
window.imagepath = plant.dataset.imagepath;
var img = document.getElementById("image");
img.src = window.imagepath;


return false;

}
</script>